# XPATH: Filtering (rather than selecting nodes), preserving hierarachy

Tags: xpath-2.0

Given the following XML (with many hierarchy levels), I need to return the nodes after filtering all nodes with Hide"True" attribute and a certain name. Note that hide could be at any hierarchy level:

```
 <items>
 <item id="1"  >
    <item id="2" />
    <item id="3" />
    <item id="4" hide="true"/>
 </item>
 <item id="5" hide="true">
 <item id="6" >
    <item id="7">
       <item id="8" hide="true"/>
       <item id="9"/>
    </item>
 </item>
 </items>
```

I would need to get this back:

```
<items>
 <item id="1"">
    <item id="2" />
    <item id="3" />
 </item>
 <item id="6" >
    <item id="7">
       <item id="9"/>
    </item>
 </item>
</items>
```

The 'filtered' XML is then assigned to a treeview, so I need to preserve the hierarchical nature of the nodes. I have tried: "items//item[@hide='false'  or not(@hide)]", but this returns a flattened (as well as duplicative) data, repeating nodes at the lower level pushed up to the top level as follows. Is there a way to use Xpath to do what I want? I understand that I can Xslt the data first, then display it, but it just seems that there is got to be an easier way. I am using c#/.net4.0 MSXML

```
<items>
 <item id="1"">
    <item id="2" />
    <item id="3" />
  </item>
 <item id="6" >
    <item id="7">
       <item id="9"/>
    </item>
 </item>
 <item id="2" />
 <item id="3" />
 <item id="7">
       <item id="9"/>
  </item>
  <item id="9"/>
</items>
```